# R optim function - N parameters

Tags: r, optimization, predictive-models, differential-equations

I am working on SIR model. I try to estimate the parameters according to datas.
Here is a code similar to what I am working with.

```
library(pomp)

niamey <- read.csv("http://kingaa.github.io/clim-dis/parest/niamey.csv")

pomp(
  data=subset(niamey,community=="A",select=-community),
  times="biweek",t0=0,
  skeleton=vectorfield(
    Csnippet("
      DS = -Beta*S*I/N;
      DI = Beta*S*I/N-gamma*I;
      DR = gamma*I;")),
  rinit=Csnippet("
      S = S_0;
      I = I_0;
      R = N-S_0-I_0;"),
  statenames=c("S","I","R"),
  paramnames=c("Beta","gamma","N","S_0","I_0")) -> niameyA

sse <- function (params) {
  x <- trajectory(niameyA,params=params)
  discrep <- x["I",,]-obs(niameyA)
  sum(discrep^2)
}

f2 <- function (par) {
  params <- c(Beta=par[3],gamma=1,N=50000,S_0=par[1],I_0=par[2])
  sse(params)
}

for (m in c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN")){
  optim(fn=f2,par=c(10000,10,8),lower = -Inf, upper = Inf,method=m) -> fit2
  print(paste("for method",m,"we have-----------------------------:"))
  print(fit2)
}
```

- What is the general idea behind multiple parameters estimation ? ie, I understant the global idea for 1 parameter but how does it works for N parameters
- I am getting errors with some methods due to number size (<e-16), is there a way to avoid it ?